# Find the lower and upper integral of f

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am having to solve the following question:

---

> Let $f,g:[a,b] \rightarrow R$, $g$ be Riemann integrable and $f$ with $f(x) = g(x)$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x) = g(x) + 1$ for $x$ irrational. Find the lower and upper integrals of $f$ in function of $g$.

---

I am not sure where to start in this situation. I tried searching for the solution, but haven't found any leads. (Mostly because the symbols difficult my search). Therefore, I have come here asking for help. If anyone could give me a hint, or something, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: It should be quite obvious that on any interval (with positive length) $\mathrm{I},$ we have $\inf f(\mathrm{I}) = \inf g(\mathrm{I})$ and similarly $\sup f(\mathrm{I}) = \sup g(\mathrm{I}) + 1.$ Hence, $U(f, P) - L(f,P) = U(g, P) - L(g,P) + 1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the case for the upper integral, and the case for the lower integral will follow by some similar reasoning. By definition
$$
\overline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx
=\inf\{U(f;P):P \text{ a partition of } [a,b]\},
$$
where $U(f;p)=\sum_{i=1}^n M_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$ and $M_i=\sup\{f(x): x_{i-1}<x<x_i\}$. Now, since the irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that for any subinterval $(x_{i-1},x_{i})$ we have $M_i = M_i^g+1$, where $M_i^g=\sup\{g(x): x_{i-1}<x<x_i\}$. Since this holds for each subinterval, we have
$$
U(f;P)
=\sum_{i=1}^n (M_i^g+1)(x_i-x_{i-1})
=U(g+1;P)
$$
for any partition $P$.
Therefore,
$$
\overline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx 
= \inf_P\{U(f;P)\}
= \inf_P\{U(g+1;P)\}
= \overline{\int_a^b} (g(x)+1)\,dx
$$

Note: the lower integral won't equal the upper, since f(x) is nowhere continuous and hence not Riemann integrable (like the Dirichlet function).

Comment: Both lower and upper integrals exist for every function; the function is Riemann integrable when these two integrals coincide.

Comment: Right - I never said the lower integral didn't exist. But at any rate I've edited the answer to clarify slightly.